# Where is the flaw in this using Rearrangement Inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, rearrangement-inequality

I assume that the reader understands by Rearrangement Inequality that if $a_i$ and $b_i$ are reals, and
$a_1 ≤ a_2 ≤ ... ≤ a_n $ and $b_1 ≤ b_2 ≤ ...≤ b_n$ then

$\Sigma_{i=0}^{i=n} a_i × b_i$ ≥ $\Sigma_{i=0}^{i=n} a_i × p_i$ ≥ $\Sigma_{i=0}^{i=n} a_i × b_{n-i}$

Where $p_1,p_2...$ are any permutations of $b_1, b_2...$

Now Statement 1: Consider 3 positive numbers $a, b$, and $c$.

WLOG, assume $a ≥ b ≥ c > 0 $
Now, $1/c ≥ 1/b ≥ 1/a$

Applying Rearrangement Inequality, we get

$a/c + b/b + c/a ≥ a/b + b/a + c/c$

Or,  $a/c + c/a ≥ a/b + b/a$

Now, the dilemma, if we had considered WLOG $a≥c≥b$ THEN the inequality would have flipped but the result should be independent of the order of $b$ and $c$ as we assumed the order without loss of generality...

I couldn't find where's the flaw in this that leads to the dilemma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** $a≥b≥c>0$ **then** $a/c+c/a ≥ a/b+b/a$.

**If** $a≥c≥b>0$ **then** $a/b+b/a ≥ a/c+c/a$.

No contradiction there...

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be independent of what we assume? The order is an assumption, so it should be a general inequality in $a$,$b$ and $c$, right?

Comment: @ChiefVS: How can you **assume** that $a≥b≥c$ but ignore that assumption? You have only proven the two **conditional** statements I stated. Look closely at the inequalities where you can assume **by symmetry** some specific ordering of the variables. The inequality you proved here under each assumption has no such symmetry.

Comment: Ah so the result is directly dependent on the assumption due to it being a non symmetric case, unlike the most other cases I was dealing with... Gotcha, thanks.

Comment: @ChiefVS: My suggestion is that you learn basic first-order logic, so that you can fully grasp logical reasoning that is used throughout mathematics. For now though, notice that your reasoning is faulty because it would also allow you to do this: "Assume without loss of generality that $a≥b$. Then $a≥b$. But if we had considered $b≥a$ then we would have gotten $b≥a$. Where is the flaw that leads to this dilemma?"

Comment: I guess you figured it out before I finished writing my last comment. =)

Comment: Yes lol. I has dealing with cases like proving Cauchy Shwaas, AM-GM-HM, or symmetric cases with conditions like $a+b+c = 1$ woth rearrangement, so I didn't notice this time that there's no symmetry.

Comment: @ChiefVS: I have no idea who downvoted your question, and I have upvoted it since I don't think it deserves a downvote. I would like to just add that some inequalities are only cyclic and not symmetric, in which case you can at most assume that either $a≥b≥c$ or $a≥c≥b$, and have to deal with both cases separately if you want to employ techniques that require knowing the order of variables.